# Find the probability to have in our hand $4$ aces if we draw randomly $6$ cards from a pack of cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Find the probability to have in our hand $4$ aces if we draw randomly $6$ cards from a pack of cards.

Could anyone give me any ideas how to approach it?

Answer (score 4):

Some hints:

Let $A$ be the number of sets of $6$ cards that include $4$ aces, and $B$ the number of sets of $6$ cards. Then your answer should be $\frac{A}{B}$.

To calculate $B$, you want to find the number of sets of $6$ cards from $52$ cards. How many sets are there?

To calculate $A$, you are including $4$ aces, so you want to find the number of sets of $6-4=2$ cards from the remaining $52-4=48$ cards. How many sets are there?

Comment: for $A$ we have two sets and for $B$ one?

Comment: good hints, no need more

Comment: $${{4 \choose 4}{48 \choose 2}\over {52 \choose 6}}$$ or am i wrong?

Comment: You're right! (And of course $\binom{4}{4}=1$)

Answer (score 1):

Number of combinations of being dealt 4 aces, and the other 2 cards not being aces I believe is;

$$x={52 \choose 1} {51 \choose 1} {50 \choose 1} {49 \choose 1} {48 \choose 2} $$

Since 1 ace is removed from the deck each time until 0 aces are left, and 2 cards are not aces.

Now the number of combinations of any 6 cards being dealt from 52 in the deck is;

$$n={52 \choose 6} $$

Hence the probability is $$\frac{x}{n}$$

Comment: I think you need to modify x.

Comment: Why does x need to be modified?

Comment: I believe you want to have $x=\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{2}$.  (See the comments beneath the other answer.)